# IRR Calculation in python with variable cash flows ( inflows and outflows )

Tags: python

I want to calculate the IRR for a bond portfolio of the previous year, having varriable cashflows.
I Know :
_the portfolio value at the start of the year (1/1/2019)
_the cashflows ( in and out ) during the year 
_the portfolio value at the end of the year (31/12/2019

[CASHFLOWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZRbT.png)

How i must call the python irr in order to calculate the IRR of the portfolio for the previous year ???

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a provider of free software solutions. Also, don’t share information as images unless absolutely necessary, which isn’t the case here.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this:
[Calculating Variable Cash-flow IRR in Python (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203735/calculating-variable-cash-flow-irr-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `numpy_financial` library.

1. Install the package with `pip install numpy-financial`
2. Do something like this:

   `import numpy_financial
   initial_investment   = -800
   cash_flows           = [initial_investment, -200, 10, 200, -100, 750] 
   irr = round(numpy_financial.irr(cash_flows), 4)
   print(f"IRR = {irr}")`

Comment: My issue is that I do not have cashflows in regular-periodic (fixed) intervals but in some days inside the year (see the IMAGE). So, somehow, i must include the time of every cashflow